# Is it possible to create a non-ecommerce site using Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have a site to develop. This site is a kind of voucher code site. Means this site will provide voucher codes for other sites. User will come to my site and pick voucher codes for an  another site and will then redirect to that site. In short, it does not need any add-to-cart functionality of magento.

An example site is shown below in link:  http://www.myvouchercodes.co.uk

However, this site require a strong admin side for support and I believe magento has a strong admin. This is the reason why I am planning to choose magento for my site. So my questions are

1)Is it good to use magento for developing such non e-commerce sites

2)What are the best practices that should take care of when developing such sites using magento

Please share your thoughts... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but Magento is good at one thing, and that is selling. Using it only as a catalog would be a waste of resources and you might be better of using another system like Typo3 or Wordpress.

At the end of the day the most important thing is that you it in a system you feel comfortable working with and the end user and administrator can work with.

But in my honest opinion: the answer would be: NO

Comment: thanks for write in. I think except selling part.. all other resources of magento is suit for this site. I have the freedom to choose platform for developing this site. I know only magento framework. dont worked in another frameworks. so which will be the best choice to develop this sort of site?

Comment: If you're still gonna use the catalog function heavily Magento will have its benefits indeed. And as I said, if you have enough experience with magento it might still be a fitting solution. Make sure you're not spending more time on ripping stuff out of Magento than building stuff